# Python webscraping does not get the particular class for this website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the contents of the class `gameLatest gameLatestHorizontal lastestHistory`

However the class does not show up for some reason when scraping it. [If you inspect the page you could see the class I am looking for and its parent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZPwa.png)

Searching for this classes parent returns all its children except the one I am looking for.

```
    def scrape():
    url = "https://bloxflip.com/crash"
    page = requests.get(url).text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    crash = doc.find_all("div", class_="gameLatest gameLatestHorizontal lastestHistory")
    print(crash)

scrape()
```

Is there any way to get the data in that class?

Comment: There is no error, the class simply does not show up when you scrape the page.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is that the content of the page changes cause it is rendered dynamically, and `requests` only get the static state.

You could search xhr requests for an api that is used to update the information or use [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/#putting-everything-together) to get the browser interpreted / manipulated `page_source`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://bloxflip.com/crash')

#### Search for element and print directly in selenium
for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.gameLatest.gameLatestHorizontal.lastestHistory'):
    print(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    
#### or grab only page_source and search with beautifulsoup
    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
soup.find_all("div", class_="gameLatest gameLatestHorizontal lastestHistory")
```

##### Output

```
<div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemNeutral" style="cursor: pointer;">1.56</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemYellow" style="cursor: pointer;">3.37</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemBlue" style="cursor: pointer;">13.36</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemYellow" style="cursor: pointer;">3.69</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemNeutral" style="cursor: pointer;">1</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemNeutral" style="cursor: pointer;">1</div><div class="gameLatestItem gameLatestItemNeutral" style="cursor: pointer;">1.57</div>
```